# DJANGO : how to run API-request in the background so my users experience no delay?

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I've a script that get's data from an API. The API needs some time to calculate and return the values.

This means that my my user experiences a lot of delay (9sec) to go to the next page, until the API has returned the values.

Is there a way to run the script with the API in the background? So the user can continue their experience without any hinder ? (I wonder if async functions can help?)

the code I use to run the API:

```
import requests            
body = {...}
headers = {
            'Accept': 'application/json, application/geo+json, application/gpx+xml, img/png; charset=utf-8',
            'Authorization': '...',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }

        call = requests.post('https://api....', json=body, headers=headers)

        print(call.status_code, call.reason)
        print(call.text)
```

---

***UPDATE:***

For those that are new to celery (like me) a quick update on the things I did to get it working.

1. Get a Redis Server up and running : [This link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-redis-on-ubuntu-20-04) explains how to do it. It's from Digital Ocean, but I used a server on Hetzner and it worked perfectly fine.
2. ... I'll update the rest as I proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classical way is to send any long-running tasks to [celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html) worker

Comment: I've been looking at some documentation. But I still got some unanswered questions. 
The thing is that I can only use the API at the end of the form, when users click on the button to go to the next page. So my question is then how can I go to the next view, and run the API in the background. Should I request the API in the next view then? Or is there another way? @victorErmakov

Comment: You can request it whenever you want. It depends on the task... Celery would add a task in the queue and run it when ready. What this API request is doing?

Comment: It is getting different isochrones (time-based) for a specific coordinate (lon/lat).  [openrouteService](https://openrouteservice.org/dev/#/api-docs/v2/isochrones/{profile}/post)

Is there a reason not to go for asyncio or sync_to_async() ? Is celery preferable ?

Comment: For example, you can create a different view and request it via JS or jQuery after form submit.

Comment: Asyncio in the same view or form not gonna help, you still need to await the result from API.

Comment: @victorEmakov , For Celery to run, I did create a redis server. But now I'm confused since this server is not where my Django app is running. Is this possible ? Or do you always need to add redis to the same server as the Django app ?

Comment: It is great! Cause it's not a good concept to run everything on one server. Also, you can run Django cache with Redis since you are using it as a broker and get rid of Memcached if you use it.

Comment: I used "CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://'+REDIS_HOST+':6379/" But when tryin to run the celery - server ('>celery -A FAM worker -l info') I got this error : ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://<IP>:6379/0: Error 10061 connecting to <IP>:6379. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it..

Comment: Maybe you should open a port on the Redis server?

Comment: I got the issue, I still had "bind 127:0:0:1" settings for redis.conf --- I changed it to "bind 0:0:0:0"

Comment: @jefferson, this issue not in celery, but Redis :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234363/discussion-between-victor-ermakov-and-jefferson).